# Magento 2.1 Category : custom layout update

Tags: magento-2.1, layout-update

I have a magento store with multiple categories. The default number of products shown on each category is 12. For a particular category I want that all its products be shown.
What are the different ways of achieving it.
Can I do it using custom layout update "Layout Update XML" - if yes what would be the xml?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#argument hope help you

Comment: you want to show for multiple category or single category ?

Comment: only single category

Answer (score 0):

Try this with layout xml specifique for your category catalog_category_view_id_{{id}}.xml

```
    <referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar"  />  
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>   
            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>10</limit></action>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: getting error 

`Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move ). Line: 1`

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

Comment: <block>
    <container>
    before and after attributes
    <action>
    <referenceBlock> and <referenceContainer>
    <move>
    <remove>
    <update>
    <argument>
    <arguments>

Comment: Can you show me error please? and can you show me all of your layout d'ont forget <page> and <body> ?